# Is it possible to have both the user Object and its userProxy Object in Active Directory? Do we have any API to retrieve userProxy objects in c++??

Tags: c++

My requirement is to retrieve the Active Directory users (user object and userProxy object) from ADAM server into my application using proper credentials.

Since we don't have any ADAM server environment, we are unable to test it. So, Is it possible to have user objects and userProxy objects both in Active Directory to test??

Are we having any API to retrieve the user and userProxy objects with application account credentials and not with individual account credentials.